# uploadify & PHP - upload cancel & page refresh issue

Tags: php, mysql, uploadify

I have integrated uploadify module in my existing programming and things work fine right now.

Now, I want to do 2 things.

1 - When I click cancel button during file uploading, file upload process is cancelled immediately and file does not upload on server but file name is stored in database. So how to prevent script so it doesn't store data in database when I cancel the uploading? Please help on this.

2 - Is is possible to refresh entire web page after file uploading process is completed? Please help on this too.

Many Thanks,
KRA

Answer (score 0):

You can use OnUploadComplete event of uploadify for this. You can save the filename of the uploaded file on completion of the upload. so if you cancle the upload in between then it will not get stored in the database.

```
$(function() {
    $("#file_upload").uploadify({
        'swf'              : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader'         : '/uploadify/uploadify.php',
        'onUploadComplete' : function(file) {
            alert('The file ' + file.name + ' finished processing.');
        }
    });
});
```

Also for second thing you can use location.reload(true) in above function to refresh the page on completion of the upload

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$targetFolder = $UPLOAD_PATH; // Relative to the root
$verifyToken = md5('unique_salt' . $_POST['timestamp']);
if (!empty($_FILES) && $_POST['token'] == $verifyToken) {
$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = $targetFolder;
$targetFileName = $int_pkid.".".$targetFileExt;;
$targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $targetFileName;

// Validate the file type
$fileTypes = array('pdf','doc','docx'); // File extensions
$fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
    echo '1';

            //Will Enter this Block only when the upload is success
            //This should fix one of you
            $str_query_insert="INSERT INTO  tr_file_data (pkid,title,filename)";
            $str_query_insert.=" VALUES(".$int_pkid.",'".${str_title}."','".${targetFileName}."')";
            ExecuteQuery($str_query_insert);

            //To Reload, there are no straight legal ways, but can do with a twist
            //Method 1:
            Header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
            Exit(); //optional
            //Method 2:
            echo '<script>parent.window.location.reload(true);</script>';




} else {
    echo 'Invalid file type.';
}
}


// To apply directly to uploadify
$(function() {
    $("#file_upload").uploadify({
        'swf'              : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader'         : '/uploadify/uploadify.php',
        'onUploadComplete' : function(file) {
            alert('The file ' + file.name + ' finished proce`enter code here`ssing.');

                //Will Enter this Block only when the upload is success
                //This should fix one of you
                $str_query_insert="INSERT INTO  tr_file_data (pkid,title,filename)";
                $str_query_insert.=" VALUES(".$int_pkid.",'".${str_title}."','".${targetFileName}."')";
                ExecuteQuery($str_query_insert);

                //To Reload, there are no straight legal ways, but can do with a twist
                //Method 1:
                Header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
                Exit(); //optional
                //Method 2:
                echo '<script>parent.window.location.reload(true);</script>';

        }
    });
});
```