# Redirect from IhttpHandler ashx.vb file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, uploadify

I have a problem with a ashx.vb file

```
Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

        Try
               /*  CODE TO UPLOAD THE FILE */

                context.Response.Redirect("~/Prodotti/STEP6.aspx", False)
                Return
            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw New Exception("Error", ex)
            End Try

        Catch ex As Exception
            Dim msg As String = GestioneErrori.TrapError(ex)
            context.Response.Write(msg)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

I use it to process the request of uploading a file using uploadify.
I need to reload the page which contains the fileUpload object.
I think context.Response.Redirect("~/Prodotti/STEP6.aspx", False)  was the only way  but it doen't work.
The file upload shows http error 302

the ashx.vb file is store in a folder at the same level of the folder which contains the page to be redirected

I tried also with

```
context.Response.Redirect("~/Prodotti/STEP6.aspx", False)
context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
```

and

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Prodotti/STEP6.aspx", False)
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
```

and

```
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Response.Redirect("~/Prodotti/STEP6.aspx", False)
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
```

and

```
Dim url As String
url = context.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower()
url = Replace(url, "step6", "step5")
context.Response.Buffer = True
context.Response.Status = "302 Object moved"
context.Response.AddHeader("Location", url)
context.Response.Write("<HTML><Head>")
context.Response.Write("<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT=""0;URL=" & url & """>")
context.Response.Write("<Script>window.location='" & url & "';</Script>")
context.Response.Write("</Head>")
context.Response.Write("</HTML>")
```

but all of them didn't work

Any idea?

thank you

Ps. I've found a similar question about it but unfortunately that doesn't solve my problem  ([response redirect from .ashx file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048974/response-redirect-from-ashx-file))

thank you

Comment: You can't do that because you've used `uploadify` (AJAX).

Comment: is there any way to do a reload of that page?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13538962/uploadify-php-upload-cancel-page-refresh-issue  This solved my problem. thank you AVD for the suggestion to check uploadify, instead of ashx.vb page